# bigfoot footnotes overrun text area

Tags: xetex, margins, footnotes, bigfoot

In writing a rather complex critical edition, I often encounter problems with XeLaTeX typesetting bigfoot footnotes so that they overrun the text area and spill into the bottom margin.  How can I eliminate or prevent this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: No MWE: too localized.